# Styling Material grid-list items

Tags: angular, angular-material

So this:

```
   <md-grid-list cols="5" rowHeight="20px">
      <md-grid-tile
          *ngFor="let carBrand of carBrands"
          colspan= 1
          rowspan= 1>
        <md-checkbox>{{ carBrand}}</md-checkbox>
      </md-grid-tile>
    </md-grid-list>
```

generates my list, but all items in cols are centered. I see in dev tools that if I change `justify-content: center` to `justify-content: left` it probably works well, but can not achieve same effect in my code.

How to properly style these?

Comment: Whats the goal?

Comment: to align items - left or right. Now they are centered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) to None on your component:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './my.component.html' ,
    styleUrls: ['./my.component.css'], 
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Then in your component css you can do exactly what you tried in the dev tools, overriding the style to `justify-content: left`

> View Encapsulation = None means that Angular does no view
>   encapsulation. Angular adds the CSS to the global styles. The scoping
>   rules, isolations, and protections discussed earlier don't apply. This
>   is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the
>   HTML.

Comment: Thanks, now I can align them left, but only if I use `!important`. Maybe I am missing something..? I imported ViewEncapsulation and added `.mat-grid-tile .mat-figure {
  justify-content: left !important;
}` to component.css